# Transparent plastic eevee

Tags: rendering, texturing, shaders, eevee-render-engine

I have the issue with back side of material when rendering transparent plastic in Eevee.

First picture attached was in RGB colour format, this is how it supposed to look.

Second picture attached is in RGBA colour format and you can see through the back side.

[image]

[image]

Blend mode of material: Alpha blend.

Screen space reflections are turned on.

Attached nodes below.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried the Backface Culling setting in eevee props ?

Comment: @Gorgious yes, it's turned on

Comment: Are your normals consistently pointing outward ?

Comment: Attaching screenshots of settings in material properties and face orientation. 

https://imgur.com/a/wuznHhu

Comment: @Gorgious so my point is that from the front side I need to see what's inside the object, but back side shouldn't be transparent. Maybe it's better to duplicate material and assign new material without transparent bsdf to back side?

Comment: @Gorgious it worked ;)